# Mysql RAND() function based on some other values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this table structure:

```
  id | product | value
-----+---------+--------
  1  |  test1  |  10
-----+---------+--------
  2  |  test2  |  30
-----+---------+--------
  3  |  test3  |  25
-----+---------+--------
  4  |  test4  |  20
-----+---------+--------
  5  |  test5  |  15
-----+---------+--------
  6  |  test6  |  35
-----+---------+--------
```

This are some products that I want to recommend to my users, and I am intrested to show 4 products on my homepage (not all of them), the most valuable products with **one exception**.

So normally I want to display all the time this products: `test6, test2, test3, test4`. The only problem is that I want from time to time to display some of the other products instead, but with a lower rate. So if I didn't want this I would probably `order by value desc`. But the thing is that I don't want my users to get bored to see the same 4 products all the time, I want from time to time to insert one or two other products in my list.

Now I know that mysql has a RAND() function but I don't know how I could use that to make a query to do exactly what I want.

Matematically it should work like this:

We add all the values togheter `10+30+25+20+15+35 = 135`, we apply the rule of thirds to see the random rate for each product.

```
135 = 100%
------------
10  = 7.4%
30  = 22.2%
25  = 18.5%
20  = 14.8%
15  = 11.1%
35  = 25.9%
```

So considering this percentages I want to make a query which will return a list of 4 products using random but also considering which product has more chances to apear based on those percentages.

Don't ask me what I tried yet because I am not an mysql expert, I know how to do this in PHP but I want to know if this is even possible using only mysql, and how I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with variables.  Take the cumulative sum, normalize it, and then use `rand()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@v := @v + value) as running_value
      from t cross join
           (select @v := 0) params
     ) t cross join
     (select sum(value) as sum_value
      from t
     ) total
order by (rand() between (t.running_value - t.value)/total.sum_value and t.running_value / total.sum_value) desc,
         rand();
```

The above can be simplified.  Also, the `rand()` in the `order by` may be re-computed a lot of times.  I think this is better:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@v := @v + value) as running_value, rand() as rnd
      from t cross join
           (select @v := 0) params
     ) t 
order by (rnd between (t.running_value - t.value)/@v and t.running_value/@v) desc;
```

EDIT:

Now that I'm thinking about it, the binary result in `order by` is quite the right thing to order by.  This is appropriate for *selecting* one row, but not necessarily for ordering.

I think this is a better approach:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rand() as rnd
      from t 
     ) t 
order by rnd * t.value desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will try this. One little question. Is this recommended or it's more faster using php ? I mean, do you encourage me to use this query?

Comment: The second query should be as good or better than doing this in php.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc' at line 6

Comment: Why it gives me a MariaDB error when in my cpanel I have MySQL® Databases and that was the section where I created my mysql database?

Comment: @paulalexandru . . . Somehow I didn't have the right condition in the `order by` clause.

Comment: damn that's some nice sql

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your correction. I tested your query, this time I don't get an error, the query gives me results, but the problem is that the results doesn't seem to work as expected. For example, I runed the query 15 times and 10 times I got the same result. I tested with 7 products and grabed the first 4 (as I mentioned in my example) and I get the same 4 very often. Meanwhile I developed a solution in PHP and I get more acurate results, the results I expected to get.

Comment: @paulalexandru . . . This query depends quite explicitly on random numbers.  It is not going to produce the same results each time.

Comment: So you think I lied?